# How To Log Changed on Laravel ServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, logging

Trying to make log system like: "User 1 changed Price field as 22$ on 22.11.2019" "User 1 add new product #41 on 22.11.2019" but couldnt reach changed data on service provider.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Product::updated(function ($user) {
            Log::info('event creating');
        });

    }
```

How can I use request parameters on that like:

```
Log::info(Auth::user()->id." has changed ".$data->product_name." price as ".$data->price." $"
```

Comment: Consider something like http://laravel-auditing.com/ or https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use monologger?

```
    use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
    use Monolog\Logger;

    $log = new Logger('LoggerNameFile');
    $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/logger.log')));
```